# getting timeout connecting to http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system

Hi guys i'm having the following problem running sudo apt-get update, any clues on what might be causing this?

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease            
Hit:8 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Err:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
  Could not connect to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (200.236.31.4). - connect (113: No route to host)
Err:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to br.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to br.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (200.236.31.4). - connect (113: No route to host)
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to br.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to br.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `br` archive server for ubuntu is throwing 504 errors right now, either wait or change the text `http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.